# How to remove small text beside the mouse pointer

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I have install virtualbox and then installed CentOS 7. Now My problem is I have this small text beside the mouse pointer. How can I remove it?  Please see the image below:

[image]

Comment: Is the small text _attached_ to the pointer?

Comment: Yes, If I move the pointer, the small move too.

Comment: Please restart the VM, if it is still there then restart your host. It will vanish.

Comment: @RubanSavvy I tried to restart the VM. But it stil there. How can I restart the host?

Comment: Restart your laptop.

Comment: @RubanSavvy Hi, I tried it. but it is still there. If I move  the pointer the small text move too.